# Globally configuring Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, configuration, angular-ui-bootstrap

Some of the [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directives, such as datepicker, have configuration instructions like this: "All settings can be provided as attributes in the `<datepicker>` or globally configured through the `datepickerConfig`."

Although the configuration options are listed, there is no description of what a `*Config` is and how I globally configure one. It sounds like this is a standard part of Angular. Is it? How do I use this configuration pattern, and where is it documented?

Comment: I do believe, it's implemented as simple setting service(factory) and directive has dependency onto it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.config(['uibDatepickerConfig', function(uibDatepickerConfig) {
    uibDatepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
}]);
```

Comment: That is wrong because as Eugene pointed out in bootstrap ui the uibDatepickerConfig is implemented as a simple service instead of using the provider stuff: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js

Comment: @arturh uibDatepickerConfig isn't a service. The angular UI docs state: "Also, some components have default values that you can override globally within a .config function for example."

Answer (score 1):

The reference documentation for using `config` is in the Angular.Module type under the [config](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#methods_config) method. However, that documentation doesn't tell you how config works. For an overview, look in the Developer Guide under [Provider Recipe](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#providers_provider-recipe).