# How to configure Angular UI bootstrap directives globally

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I configure the [bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) using `uibDatepickerConfig` globally? The documentation just says the following:

> All settings can be provided as attributes in the `uib-datepicker` or globally configured through the `uibDatepickerConfig`.

In the [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js), they are defined as *constants*:

```
.constant('uibDatepickerConfig', {
    formatDay: 'dd',
    formatMonth: 'MMMM',
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    formatDayHeader: 'EEE',
    formatDayTitle: 'MMMM yyyy',
    formatMonthTitle: 'yyyy',
    datepickerMode: 'day',
    minMode: 'day',
    maxMode: 'year',
    showWeeks: true,
    startingDay: 0,
    yearRange: 20,
    minDate: null,
    maxDate: null,
    shortcutPropagation: false
})
```

---

The exact same issue was already discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785999/globally-configuring-angular-directives) but the solution seems to be **outdated**.

Comment: Have you tried that solution?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Yes I have. It's not working (anymore) since they are not using *providers*. Maybe this has changed during last year.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NpS0QtA88ZBzxBQMXfIE?p=preview (just example from angular bootstrap page) works as in that solution (just added 'uib' to name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//where app is the module that depends on 'ui.bootstrap'
// probably your main app module

//for DatePicker options
app.config(['uibDatepickerConfig', function (uibDatepickerConfig) {
    uibDatepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
}]);

//for DatePickerPopup options
app.config(['uibDatepickerPopupConfig', function (uibDatepickerPopupConfig) {
    uibDatepickerPopupConfig.closeText= 'Close';
    uibDatepickerPopupConfig.placement = 'auto bottom';
}]);
```

Comment: the uibDatepickerConfig is not defined. You are missing the injection of that variable.

Comment: angular is able to inject it, as far as you don't minify/uglify.

Comment: Didn't know, on my side it's giving me an error for some reasons

Comment: So that's why it didn't work. I was required to prefix uib. Thanks a lot! The popup works the same: uibDatepickerPopupConfig